# How to 'cd' to a directory found with 'find'?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, ruby, cd-command

I have a file in `gmail.rb` in the below directory:

```
root@ubuntu:~# find / -name gmail.rb|more

/media/aruprakshit/FA686DE4686DA05D/Rubyscript/gmail.rb
```

But when i am trying to reach to the `Rubyscript` using `cd` getting error as:

```
$ cd Rubyscript
bash: cd: Rubyscript: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me by saying what I did wrong?

Comment: while typing long directory paths, tab is your friend.  press tab twice to list available files (can even do partial matching by typing the first letters of a file before hitting tab twice)

Comment: @dkaczynski seems a good tip it is. Can you bit detail your comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your prompt says:

```
Peter@ubuntu:~$
```

The part between `:` and `$` is:

```
~
```

That represents the folder you're currently in. `~` is shorthand for your home folder (`/home/Peter`). See [this section of the Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands) for more information about abbreviations in directory names, and related concepts.

You ran the command `cd Rubyscript`. The folder name after `cd` did not start with a `/`, so it is a relative path--relative to your current location (which is `/home/Peter`). `cd Rubyscript`, run from there, is thus equivalent to:

```
cd /home/Peter/Rubyscript
```

But the `Rubyscript` folder is not located in `/home/Peter`. As the `find` command said, it's located in `/media/aruprakshit/FA686DE4686DA05D`.

Therefore, you should run this command instead:

```
cd /media/aruprakshit/FA686DE4686DA05D/Rubyscript
```

**That will get you there.** (Assuming you have permission to enter that folder. Which you probably do--its volume name looks like a UUID, and its length indicates it's probably an NTFS volume. If you mounted an NTFS volume, you usually can enter any folder within it and perform any read or write action.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for your corrections, it works for me. :)

Comment: @EliahKagan could you tell me where I can ask `Ruby` specific questions? just as for help I asked.

Comment: @eliah-kagan Why you don't say than is ~ tilda? :D

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU If it's about how to use the Ruby interpreter and tools, including installing Ruby packages, you can ask here on Ask Ubuntu. If it's about writing programs with Ruby, usually you should ask that at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead, though if the question is in some way Ubuntu-specific, it would be welcome here. There are probably a number of other Ruby resources I'm just not familiar with, too.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `Rubyscript` in your `~` directory. You should type:

```
cd /media/aruprakshit/FA686DE4686DA05D/Rubyscript
```

Comment: No, I can see the directory sir, :) Okay let me give it a try as you said.